# Google Maps Street view Breakage

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-street-view

[image]We are using Google street view Api Version 3 for our product. We are facing an issue when the street view is loading for the first time. The view is breaking in to pieces/pix, where as when we see the same view in Google maps it is not breaking but the imaginary is showing Blur effect. How we can give the same **blur effect** in our product also?`
Click this link to see the breaking effect: http://jsfiddle.net/godwinthaya/4wfLkc3t/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Street View service</title>
    <style>
      html, body, #map-canvas {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"></script>
    <script>
function initialize() {
  var fenway = new google.maps.LatLng(42.345573, -71.098326);
  var mapOptions = {
    center: fenway,
    zoom: 14
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

//marker
  var busMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: fenway,
      map: map,
      icon: 'http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_icon&chld=bus|FFFF00',
      title: 'Bus Stop'
  });
   var panoramaOptions = {
    position: fenway,
    pov: {
      heading: 34,
      pitch: 10
    }
  };
  var panorama = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), panoramaOptions);
    map.setStreetView(fenway);

     panorama.setPov(/** @type {google.maps.StreetViewPov} */({
    heading: 265,
    pitch: 0
  }));


   google.maps.event.addListener(busMarker, 'click', function() {
   alert("Hai");
    infowindow.open(map,busMarker);
  });


}


google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!--<div id="map-canvas" style="width: 400px; height: 300px"></div> -->
    <div id="map-canvas" style="position:absolute;  width: 1000px; height: 600px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean.  Your jsfiddle looks OK to me (although zoomed in more than I would like and I don't see a marker).  What browser are you using?  Is the issue browser specific?

Comment: @geocodezip:- we have attached the screenshot of the picture in which the 3D view is breaking. We are facing this issue in all browsers. When we move from one PANO to another PANO we are facing this issue. whereas in Google maps (New maps and Classic maps) it will give Blur effect. How we can implement the same Blurring effect in our Project?

Answer (score 0):

Are you calling the events correctly? What you are asking could most likely be a part of the API but there is no documentation or reference as to implement the "blurred effect". Although, if you call all the events correctly, it should give you the default behavior. Here's the sample code for the different events:

```js
var cafe = new google.maps.LatLng(37.869085, -122.254775);

function initialize() {

  var panoramaOptions = {
    position: cafe,
    pov: {
      heading: 270,
      pitch: 0
    },
    visible: true
  };
  var panorama = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(document.getElementById('pano'), panoramaOptions);

  google.maps.event.addListener(panorama, 'pano_changed', function() {
      var panoCell = document.getElementById('pano_cell');
      panoCell.innerHTML = panorama.getPano();
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(panorama, 'links_changed', function() {
      var linksTable = document.getElementById('links_table');
      while (linksTable.hasChildNodes()) {
        linksTable.removeChild(linksTable.lastChild);
      }
      var links = panorama.getLinks();
      for (var i in links) {
        var row = document.createElement('tr');
        linksTable.appendChild(row);
        var labelCell = document.createElement('td');
        labelCell.innerHTML = '<b>Link: ' + i + '</b>';
        var valueCell = document.createElement('td');
        valueCell.innerHTML = links[i].description;
        linksTable.appendChild(labelCell);
        linksTable.appendChild(valueCell);
      }
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(panorama, 'position_changed', function() {
      var positionCell = document.getElementById('position_cell');
      positionCell.firstChild.nodeValue = panorama.getPosition() + '';
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(panorama, 'pov_changed', function() {
      var headingCell = document.getElementById('heading_cell');
      var pitchCell = document.getElementById('pitch_cell');
      headingCell.firstChild.nodeValue = panorama.getPov().heading + '';
      pitchCell.firstChild.nodeValue = panorama.getPov().pitch + '';
  });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

: